# DataGrid scrollbar thumb changes size during scrolling

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, virtualization

I have a grid that has rows in varying heights. I noticed that when I scroll down the grid, the scrollbar thumb changes its height.

After some investigations I discovered that this is caused by UI virtualization: the grid doesn't create all the items so it doesn't know the total height of the grid, so instead it determines the total height by calculating the average row height of the rows it did create, and multiply this by the row count. This causes the thumb to change its size during scrolling since the virtualization creates new items and destroys the ones that are no longer displayed, which makes the grid think the total grid size has changed.

**My question**: Is there a way I can set the scroll thumb size myself using my own heuristics? Preferably with a non-intrusive way so I won't have to re-template my control. Disabling virtualization is not an option.

[image]
[image]

Note: I'm using DevExpress DataGrid, but this behavior also happens for WPF DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a template to [style your scrollbar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF)?

Notice in the link that you can specifically style the *thumb*...
Regarding your comment, You can also attempt to bind to the number of items in the DataGrid and perform whatever calculation you want to make the size of the thumb dynamic based on the number of items.

Comment: Is it possible in this solution to adjust the thumb size according to the number of items? If so, an example would be helpful.